# How can I improve the write performance of Apache Drill

Tags: java, apache-drill

I'm using `CTAS` statement to create a parquet file from a csv in Apache Drill.
I've tried multiple experiments changing various configuration parameters, even trying to write to tmpfs.

My tests always take the same amount of time. I'm not IO bound. I may be CPU bound, consistently one java thread is at 100% most of the time.

Experiments tried:

```
store.parquet.compression=none
store.parquet.page-size=8192
planner.slice_target=10000
store.parquet.block-size=104857600
store.text.estimated_row_size_bytes=4k
```

I've reached the conclusion that perhaps Drill is single threaded for writing, can anybody confirm this?

With a 12 core server I have plenty of headroom available that is not being utilised.

Is it possible to run multiple drillbits on a single server?

Update:
It appears that the performance is the same whether the CTAS output format is csv or parquet, so the limitation appears to the ability Drill to write data in general.

Update 2:
Switching from using a csv file as input to the CTAS statement without a header, using a statement of the form:

CREATE TABLE  (col1, col2, col3, ...) AS SELECT columns[0], columns[1], column[2] from `filename`;

to using a CSV file with header, ie changing the statement to something like:

CREATE TABLE  (name1, name2, name3, ...) AS SELECT name1, name2, name3 from `filename`;

Where name1, name2 etc are defined in the header line made a significant difference in performance, from a consistent 13 minutes to execute overall process to 9 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run multiple drillibits on a single server.

Yes, In my observation also drill uses lots of Process power many times the CPU usage goes to 300-400% when we're computing on large set of data & i think it uses single thread for parquet file.

Comment: Agreed when running a query Drill is reliably using more than one core, however for CTAS statement when writing, particularly large amounts of data this appears to be limited to a single thread/core.

Comment: Actually Drill can use multiple threads when writing data to disk, it depends on the size of the data and the query

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is needed to achieve this?  The files I'm writing are about 500MB, I've tried both parquet and csv, based on the evidence the process is definitely CPU bound.  Drill 1.6.